# How to properly resize images

Tags: support, image

I've noticed a few times that the images I include in my posts got resized. It happened with at least 5 users, often rather active here, so I'll post this info as a meta post. I appreciate the gesture but would like to point out how to properly resize images on SE.

---

[image] Good: lossless resizing by using HTML tags to set the dimension. Example:

Code:

```
[<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qalR8.png" height="400" alt="IMG: " title="">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qalR8.png)
```

Output:

[image: IMG:]

---

[image] Bad: lossy resizing by re-uploading a lower quality of the image, or using the `m` and `s` imgur flag, which also decreases the displayed image quality.

Output:

[image: IMG:]

---

Side-by-side comparison. Left = lossless (good). Right = lossy (bad).

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 3):

Related discussions on Meta Stack Exchange: [Resizing an image in a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25051/resizing-an-image-in-a-post), [Please do something to encourage people to scale down their giant heavyweight photos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101439/please-do-something-to-encourage-people-to-scale-down-their-giant-heavyweight-ph?noredirect=1&lq=1).

To be fair, there's no "proper" way of resizing an image on Stack Exchange. It's back to individual preferences.

One of the issues of using the `<image>` HTML tag is that *the original image is still loaded*, and depending on the image type (especially animation), it can be as big as 2 MB per image. This may affect the user experience for those who don't have a good internet connection and also possibly waste their limited internet quota (please consider those users too!).

Ideally, *the images shown on the post directly should be size-efficient*, while they can be linked back to the original size for further use if/when needed.

Comment: Thanks, I prefer sharp/HD images over light images. The vast majority of SE users have no issue downloading HD images. People with quota can prevent images from getting displayed automatically. Resizing by re-uploading a lower quality of the image, esp. if no link to the HD image, results in the image being more difficult to back up.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt if it's sharp images for you and no images for them then, forgive me, I prefer you needing an extra click for the HD image and them having the ability to at least get an idea by seeing the ligght one ;) No offense meant. Actually, when I upload images I usually try to optimize them first to keep them small in size while still having the needed details. As usual, one cannot do it right for all people all the time…

Comment: @Izzy I prefer sharp images for 99% of users and no images for 1% of users instead of fuzzy images for 100% of users.